# Unit Testing class with Logger gets Premature end of file

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging

How do I unit test methods of a class that contains a `final static logger`? I don't need or necessarily want it to log anything at all, yet when I run my unit test that should pass I get

```
[Fatal Error] log4j2.xml:1:151: Premature end of file.
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing C:\...\MyProject\target\classes\log4j2.xml
```

Should I mock it, ignore it somehow, or what? I don't want it to log for tests but I obviously need it to log when the app itself is executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of over complicating the problem with trying to mock, or somehow get around it logging, I opted for just letting the logging happen. I just don't allow it to write to my log directory, nor do I print it to the console. I solved my problem basically by simply making a `src/test/resources` folder, creating a `log4j2.xml` and tossing this in there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" shutdownHook="disable">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">./logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="info"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```